# How to save vcard from qr code to contacts

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing, vcf-vcard

I need to save to contacts if the `qr code` contains v card. I was trying to do that with [this](https://github.com/mangstadt/ez-vcard) library but I could not read the v card information, I don't know which method is to use for that. I have seen a lot other similar posts but unfortunately those couldn't save me. I am using `zxing library` to read qr codes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

vCard is actually a bit verbose. You can use the [MECARD format](https://www.nttdocomo.co.jp/english/service/developer/make/content/barcode/function/application/addressbook/index.html) instead.

Here you can see an example string from the [ZXing Wiki](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Barcode-Contents#user-content-contact-information):

```
MECARD:N:Owen,Sean;ADR:76 9th Avenue, 4th Floor, New York, NY 10011;TEL:12125551212;EMAIL:srowen@example.com;;
```

Now for the vCard format, I can see there's a class named [`VCardResultParser`](https://zxing.github.io/zxing/apidocs/com/google/zxing/client/result/VCardResultParser.html) in the ZXing javadoc, and apparently it supports vCard v2.1. I made this small example stripping down some fields from the example in the [wikipedia page for vCard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard):

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:Gump;Forrest
ORG:Bubba Gump Shrimp Co.
TEL;WORK;VOICE:555
ADR;HOME:;;42 Plantation St.;Baytown;LA;30314;USA
EMAIL;PREF;INTERNET:forrestgump@example.com
END:VCARD
```

In both cases, you just have to serialize the fields to a plain text string and then you encode it onto a QRCode as usual. I tested both examples with a Samsung phone and when you scan them with ZXing, the leftmost button allows you to add a new contact. The contacts app opens, you press the "+" button and a new contact is created with the provided fields filled up.